# Android. WebView and loadData

Tags: android, encoding, webview

It's possible to use following method for content's setting of a web-view
loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)

How to handle the problem with unknown encoding of html data?!

Is there a list of encodings?!

I know from my college that in my case html comes from DB and is encoded with latin-1.
I try to set encoding parameter to latin-1, to ISO-8859-1 / iso-8859-1, but still have problem with displaying of special signs like ä, ö, ü.

I'll be very thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 211):

```
myWebView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

This works flawlessly, especially on Android 4.0, which apparently ignores character encoding **inside** HTML.

Tested on 2.3 and 4.0.3.

In fact, I have no idea about what other values besides "base64" does the last parameter take. Some Google examples put null in there.

Comment: This can not work "flawlessly" if you have characters outside US-ASCII charset.

Comment: Just tried on a 4.2.2 device and works like a charm, but on a 2.3.6 device it just shows the same garbage characters. :S

Comment: This also works for me in 4.1.2 (who also ignores charset inside HTML), and with a Latin1 encoding! Go figure.

Comment: @Frank Same here, tested on HTC one 2.3.7 (probably all gingerbread) and got the same garbage, I has to use Andrey Novikov solution with `WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()`

Comment: Whats the difference between your answer and: myWebView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says it assumes US-ASCII on anything else than `"base64"`, including `null`.

Comment: base64 is needed as per google recommendation. Read more here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata/54614344#54614344 and check out Google's video about that! (link in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 149):

WebView.loadData() is not working properly at all. What I had to do was:

```
String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
myWebView.loadData(header+myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I think in your case you should replace UTF-8 with latin1 or ISO-8859-1 both in header and in WebView.loadData().

And, to give a full answer, here is the official list of encodings: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

**I update my answer to be more inclusive:**

To use [WebView.loadData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with non latin1 encodings you have to encode html content. Previous example was not correctly working in Android 4+, so I have modified it to look as follows:

```
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(htmlString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    myWebView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
} else {
    String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
    myWebView.loadData(header + htmlString, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

}
```

But later I have switched to [WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and the code became very clean and not depending on Android version:

```
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

For some reason these functions have completely different implementation.

Comment: Privet, Andrey. I've tried your solution. Unfortunately it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 as I described? Now when I think about your question it occurs to me that in Java all strings are in UTF-8, so my example should work intact.

Comment: All Strings are UTF-8, but the text coming from server is in latin-1. I think, I tried with UTF-8 and with latin-1 and with ISO-8859-1, but saw still strange signs instead of ü, ö, ä. But I have another idea, I'll try to convert byte stream from server into string using right encoding. maybe, that'll help me

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is there. Try to test output this string to Toast or Dialog and see what you get.

Comment: loadData(string, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8"); worked for me!

Comment: in 4.0+ encoding should be set in mime type too "text/html; chartset=utf-8", otherwise it won't be recognised

Comment: Last snippet (the one with loadDataWithBaseURL) works great both on a 4.2.2 and 2.3.6 devices :D

Comment: myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL solved my problems with Oreo+. The web view was failing to render anything beforehand.

Comment: This is NOT right. google made some clear recommendation to use base64. See my answer and DO CHECK the video talk ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata/54614344#54614344

Answer (score 41):

As I understand it, `loadData()` simply generates a `data:` URL with the data provide it.

Read the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for `loadData()`:

> If the value of the encoding parameter is 'base64', then the data must be encoded as base64. Otherwise, the data must use ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and use the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range. For example, '#', '%', '\', '?' should be replaced by %23, %25, %27, %3f respectively.
>
> The 'data' scheme URL formed by this method uses the default US-ASCII charset. If you need need to set a different charset, you should form a 'data' scheme URL which explicitly specifies a charset parameter in the mediatype portion of the URL and call loadUrl(String) instead. Note that the charset obtained from the mediatype portion of a data URL always overrides that specified in the HTML or XML document itself.

Therefore, you should either use US-ASCII and escape any special characters yourself, or just encode everything using Base64. The following should work, assuming you use UTF-8 (I haven't tested this with latin1):

```
String data = ...;  // the html data
String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data.getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

Comment: This reminded me to check documentation before wandering everywhere !

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Was loading different built in contextual html help in a webview, and it only worked some of the time. This has fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

I have this problem, but:

```
String content = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body>";
content += mydata + "</body></html>";
WebView1.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

not work in all devices. And I merge some methods:

```
String content = 
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"+
       "<html><head>"+
       "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"+
       "</head><body>";

content += myContent + "</body></html>";

WebView WebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebView1.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

It works.

Comment: This is NOT what Google recommend. See my answer and DO CHECK the video talk ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata/54614344#54614344

Comment: I had similar problems with loadData, in my case I found that simple saving my html content to a file and then using webview.loadURL("file:///$filesDir/myfile.html") worked.

Answer (score 13):

The **safest** way to load htmlContent in a Web view is to:

1. use base64 encoding (official recommendation)
2. specify UFT-8 for html content type, i.e., "text/html; charset=utf-8" instead of "text/html" (personal advice)

"Base64 encoding" is an **official** recommendation that has been written again (already present in Javadoc) in the **latest 01/2019 bug in Chrominium** (present in WebView M72 (72.0.3626.76)):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929083

**OFFICIAL statement from CHROMIUM TEAM:**

"Recommended fix:
Our team recommends you encode data with Base64. We've provided examples for how to do so:

- API docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)
- Video talk: https://youtu.be/HGZYtDZhOEQ?t=598 (jump to 9:58)

This fix is backwards compatible (it works on earlier WebView versions), and should also be future-proof (you won't hit future compatibility problems with respect to content encoding)."

**Example:**

```
webView.loadData(
    Base64.encodeToString(
        htmlContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        Base64.DEFAULT
    ), // encode in Base64 encoded 
    "text/html; charset=utf-8", // utf-8 html content (personal recommendation)
    "base64" // always use Base64 encoded data: NEVER PUT "utf-8" here (using base64 or not): This is wrong!
);
```

Answer (score 12):

use this:
 String   customHtml =text ;

```
           wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,customHtml,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: 15 post later and this is the only one that worked for me

Comment: As crazy as this may look, this is the only workaround that worked for me with AndroidX.

Answer (score 5):

```
 String strWebData="html...." //**Your html string**

 WebView webDetail=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

 WebSettings websetting = webDetail.getSettings();

 websetting.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

 webDetail.loadData(strWebData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

the answers above doesn't work in my case. You need to specify utf-8 in meta tag

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- you content goes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is fast and working // data = any html or math string

```
public void putInWebview(String data, WebView wv) {
        String htmlstring = "<head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES' user-scalable='no'><script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']],processEscapes: true},\"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: \"container\" } } } )</script><script id=\"MathJax-script\" async src=\"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js\" ></script></head>" +
                "<body style=\"font-size:100%; font-family: Arial \"  > " + data + "</body></html>";
        String qstnencodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(htmlstring.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadData(qstnencodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");

    }
```