# UTF-8 encoding on WebView and ICS

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

To correctly display UTF-8 text in a `WebView`, I usually use a `doctype` and a `meta` tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and I use a tip I've seen on Stack Overflow:

```
string = URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", " ");
```

That works fine on Gingerbread and older Android versions, but my Nexus S recently received the Ice Cream Sandwich update, and French characters like `é`, `à`, `è`, etc. are displayed like this: `Ã©`, for example.

I don't know if the ISO-xxxx-1 encoding is the solution, but if someone had the same problem, please share.

[image: img]

Comment: You might be interested by this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9312031/62921

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android. WebView and loadData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the method loadDataWithBaseURL with random String for the other params instead of loadData

Comment: i solve the problem by keeping the doctype, remove the URLEncoder.encode method, and call 2 others methods lika that : webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: I'm not being able to show the inverted exclamation point (¡, &#161;, &iexcl;) using any of these methods. Does anyone know how to work this around?