# Web view Error using HTML content in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

```
Errors I am getting when passing Html(textstring) content value to webview.loaddata(textstring , "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Works fine in gingerbread,jellybean etc....but facing problem in Ice cream sandwich....Please help me to solve this

```
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1671)
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7800(WebViewCore.java:920)
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1783)
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2858)
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:586)
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
02-08 13:52:56.899: W/webcore(1694):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:977)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512282/android-eventhub-removemessagesint-what-107-is-not-supported-before-the-we

Comment: will you need to load some text using webview?

Comment: As per the link I have tried it all. But still getting this warning, thus it is opening in emulator but not in devices. Can you please tell me the reason for this bug. Why it is happening?????Because it is working fine in others devices

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj yes....HTML value....using asynctask getting that value and passing that value to the webview.loaddata().

Comment: i post the answer that will work for me i hope also will work for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this I this that will help to you

```
String data = ...;  // the html data
String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data.getBytes("UTF-8"),  
android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

and you try this also

```
   webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");      
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

And also refer this link

[UTF-8 encoding on WebView and ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572818/utf-8-encoding-on-webview-and-ics)

Comment: No...Still getting that warning. This is my HTML data  <html><body>"

                       + "<p align=\"justify\">"                

                        + "<font color='white' style='line-height:1.2em; font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px; font-family:Times New Roman' >"+textcastdet+"</font>"

                       + "</p>"

                       + "</body></html>

Comment: posting an answer is nice, but posting why you think the error occurs and how you think your solution helps is even better.

Comment: WebView wvtxtcastdet; public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.filmdetailspg); wvtxtcastdet=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewfilmdet);
        System.out.println("IM  3");
        wvtxtcastdet.setBackgroundColor(0);

Comment: wvtxtcastdet.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wvtxtcastdet.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);        new CastdetAsync().execute(); Asynctask

Comment: hi ARIJIT i have edited my comment please see that and i hop that will be help to u