# Coding issue with webview

Tags: android

I've uploaded my app on the playstore and for me and the most majority of users everything works fine.
Some users,however, complained about latin accempted letters like àèìòù saying strange symbols appear in their place. On my phone these letters are successfully displayed and so on my friends' phones...I can't understand where is the problem!
I load my data like this:

```
view.loadData("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html\"; charset=\"UTF-8\" />"+
                                            myText, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I'm not sure. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3961589/940096) may helps you

Comment: whose answer in particular? I can see different theories...

Comment: @Phate try adding `<html></html>` tags. Described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10571946/1216542).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to [@Sabre's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898037/coding-issue-with-webview/13311678#comment17470625_12898037) link:

> try adding `<html></html>` tags. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571946/1216542).