# different behavior between webview's loadUrl() and loadData()

Tags: android, android-webview

```
webview.loadUrl("http://example.com/image.gif");
```

loads an animated gif

```
webview.loadData("<img src='http://example.com/image.gif'/>","text/html", "UTF-8");
```

loads a static image

```
webview.loadUrl("http://example.com/gif.html");
```

loads a page where every gif is not animated.

i've tested this on the emulator and on my galaxy tab 10.1 running 4.0.4. I've seen some apps that load a webview with a page and they have animated gifs soo i must be missing something.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

doesn't change anything and i've tried http://code.google.com/p/slidetypekeyboard/source/browse/trunk/assets/index.html but it wont animate the gif either

what i'm asking : how to enable gif animation with .loadData() ? To expand, i want

```
webview.loadData("<center><img src='http://example.com/image.gif'/><center>","text/html", "UTF-8");
```

to display the animated gif.

Comment: do you mean loadData or loadUrl? you havent mentioned loadData in your post other than in the "what im asking" bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249537/1778352) answer helps me. It has a different theme, but main trick is that

**"For some reason loadDataWithBaseURL and loadData functions have completely different implementation."**

Try this:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<center><img src='http://example.com/image.gif'/><center>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: how to load if the image is from internal source?

Comment: @Cristiana214, you can do something like this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example)