# web view doesnot render text correclty in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-webview

i have a webview which is gets data form the previous page like this

```
country = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"><style type=\"text/css\">p{text-align:justify;font-size:125%;}</style></head><body>" + "<p>" + i.getStringExtra("country").toString()+"</p>"+"</body></html>";
```

when i try to set that to  a webview
`web.loadData(country, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

it shows plain text

when i try the following

```
web.loadData( URLEncoder.encode(country).replaceAll("\\+", " "), "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString());
```

it just shows

`<` and nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

loadData(country, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

Found in:

[Android. WebView and loadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata)

Comment: this is of no use its wrong wont work shows plain text