# Turkish characters are not shown on TextView

Tags: android, utf-8, textview

Turkish characters are not shown on `TextView`. I have read previous questions and did some changes and they are not solved my problem. Here is picture:

[image]

Here is my changed code:

```
holder.txtGazeteName.setText(Html.fromHtml(gazetelerArrayList.get(position).getName()).toString());
```

here is input for ArrayList

```
gazete = new GazetelerClass();
        gazete.setName("YeniŞafak");
        gazete.setAdress("http://www.yenisafak.com.tr/yazarlar/");
        gazete.setImage(R.drawable.yenisafak);
        gazetelerArrayList.add(gazete);
```

Comment: seems like you are using `version 4.0.3` !!!!

Comment: @der golem I putting data to arraylist and getting them in there.@maven what would be if I use 4.0.3

Comment: @Der Golem, they already in xml layout files.They come as default.I have checked that

Comment: Moreover,If I add turkish character in xml they are shown but in code to add  they are not shown

Comment: It sounds like the source HTML has not correctly decoded on input to Android/Java. What's the source of `gazetelerArrayList.get(position).getName()` ?

Comment: see the editted question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here is solution:

in build.gradle(module:app) added this code:

```
compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1254'
```

here is build gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1254'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yazlm.beyaz.keyazarlar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread should do the trick for you. I remembered having a similar kind of problem. [Android. WebView and loadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata/9312031#9312031)

Comment: mate i dont use webview. and searched similiar problems and all of them use webview. my problem occur in textview. I should accamplish to show turkish character in textview