# Turkish characters don't appear in Android

Tags: android

I have this xml :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_mytv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

And I have this Java :

```
TextView mytv;
mytv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mytv);
mytv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>ğüşçı</p>"));
```

When I run the emulator, All I get is question marks in diamond shaped icons. How can I make my app display Turkish characters? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio with gradle?

Comment: you have set UTF-8 in your Android Studio?

Comment: @Carnal yes I'm using Android Studio with Gradle.

Comment: @AnandSingh I have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in Android manifest if that's what you are asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309037/turkish-characters-are-not-shown-on-textview

Comment: @jason no, see image i posted in my answer. If not set, then set it. and try. might it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the charset is set to UTF-8/16 or ISO-8859-9 (Turkish charset). If that doesn't solve the problem, it could be the font itself. Try running the app on a real device to see if it works.

**EDIT -**

You can also try unicode charecters. For example - http://unicode-table.com/

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how I can check charset? Thanks.

Comment: To write charset, use <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“YOUR CHARSET”?> in the first line of XML. Replace YOUR CHARSET with the specific charset.