# Android webview automatically decode string

Tags: android, android-webview

We have send a POST request to android web view , but the web view did some url decode automatically and the server side get a wrong data.

Eg: we have a signature value like aedTH5634+hjsGT78-67ty when we POST this value through webview , webview automatically convert + value to space.SO in the server signature value is wrong.How I Avoid this decode.

IOS webview workig fine it send exact value what we have POST.How we avoid this decoding from the android webview.

Help is highly appreciable,

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Chasing the same thing now

Comment: @vks did you find a solution to this

Comment: @war_Hero Did anyone found any solution to this?

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

not sure how it will help others with a similar situation but i will still give my $0.02, I was able to solve my issue like this, I used the following methods and ensured that the encoding is retained for encoding value use base64 and convert the data to base 64, read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String))

> void loadData (String data, 
>                   String mimeType, 
>                   String encoding)

convert data to base64 like this

```
String base64Data = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(yourdata.getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**and finally put everything together like this**

```
webView.loadData(base64Data, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

Comment: also this answer was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an Android WebView Bug? 
Just a workaround:

```
webView.loadUrl(URLEncoder.encode(yourStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

code works.

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
    this.evaluateJavascript(javascriptCommand, null);
} else {
    this.loadUrl(javascriptCommand); 
}
```