# How to display html iso-8859-1 in Android Webview

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, webview

I am loading an html page in a Webview but for special characters such as `ü` and `ä`. I got question marks in place of it. Is there a simple way to solve this or do I have to make it go through an input reader?

```
public class Termine extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_termine);
       WebView terminListe = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.termin_liste);
       terminListe.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return true;
          }


       });

       terminListe.loadUrl("http://www.arsdecora.net/termine.html");

   }
}
```

Comment: Does the page contain the proper encoding attributes?

Comment: Might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata) be a possible solution?

Comment: I found out, that adding <meta charset="iso-8859-1"> solves the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusSchmitz Glad you solved it. Please accept your own answer to close the question (by checking it).

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of testing around and the comment by Kayaman, I have found out, that setting the html's meta charset to , everything is displayed fine.

Caution: This only works if you have access to the html directly!

Comment: No, actually You can modify html file on the fly, or execute javascript function in webview.