# turkish character encoding in android

Tags: android, android-studio, character-encoding

I have a problem about turkish characters in Android Studio. I clicked File >  Settings. Default Encoding, IDE and Project Encoding are Windows-1254. But i still get wrong characters in my code.

My wrong code is :

```
    public void showAlertExit() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setTitle("��k��");
    alertbox.setCancelable(false);
    alertbox.setMessage("��k�� yapmak istedi�inize emin misiniz?");
    alertbox.setNegativeButton("Hay�r",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            arg0.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Evet",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertbox.create();  
    alert.show();
}
```

I clicked "Invalidate caches/Restart" but still wrong. 
If i do "Right click -> File Encoding -> Windows-1254 -> Convert -> Convert Anyway", My code is seem that :

```
    public void showAlertExit() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setTitle("??k??");
    alertbox.setCancelable(false);
    alertbox.setMessage("??k?? yapmak istedi?inize emin misiniz?");
    alertbox.setNegativeButton("Hay?r",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            arg0.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Evet",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertbox.create();  
    alert.show();
}
```

Please someone help me :(

Comment: You can try these solutions :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata

Comment: my problem is not about webview.

Comment: Your problem: `If i do "Right click -> File Encoding -> Windows-1254 -> Convert -> Convert Anyway"`. Solution Choose **Unicode UTF-8**, instead.

Comment: it's already UTF-8. if i want to convert windows-1254, they're decay

Comment: **It has to be UTF-8**. Because `windows-1254` is **not valid** on Android, which is **UNIX**. So, you should change the encoding on your SOURCE text and make it **UTF-8**.