# How can I display <ruby> element in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("２６<ruby>日<rt>にち</rt></ruby>から"));
```

But `Html.fromHtml` doesn't support [ruby element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) well. `<rt>` elements will be omitted in the textview.  Is there any workaround? I have a list of such `TextView`, so `WebView` is inefficient.

Edit: I tried `WebView`, and it worked better than I thought. [Be careful with encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571946/5006372).

Comment: `ruby ` tag is not supported by fromHtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android seems support the following **HTML tags to be rendered on TextView**.

```
<a href=”…”> <b>,  <big>, <blockquote>, <br>, <cite>, <dfn>
<div align=”…”>,  <em>, <font size=”…” color=”…” face=”…”>
<h1>,  <h2>, <h3>, <h4>,  <h5>, <h6>
<i>,  <img src=”…”>,  <p>, <small>
<strike>,  <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <tt>, <u>
```

So `ruby` tag is not supported in here .

- *Is there any workaround?* For your `ruby` -**NO**

Comment: You mean there is no easy way to display ruby? That's crucial

Comment: I see [NHK Easy Japanese News](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aovill.language.e2l.ejn) looks like using `ruby`. What tools can I use to find which widget it's using?

Answer (score 0):

[This project called RubySpan](https://github.com/mljli/rubyspan) has a solution. It does this by extending `ReplacementSpan`.

> RubySpan is an attempt to display ruby annotation along with text
>   using Android TextView. Compared to the WebView solution, using
>   RubySpan with TextView is a lot faster, flexible and more friendly to
>   layouts. Current implementation focuses on displaying furigana on
>   Japanese kanji. But you can easilly adapt it to your application. The
>   minimal API supported is API 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop). Since
>   layouting text is a complex thing, there're still some bugs and the
>   result is not perfect if you compare it with that produced by the
>   browser or WebView.