# Difference between WebView.loadData and .loadUrl

Tags: java, android

When I load a html file with `.loadUrl` in a `WebView` control, it works fine.

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/phonetest.html");
```

When I read the same data into a `String` and use `.loadData`, the control stays blank. The `TextView` shows an exact match with the html from the file.

```
try( InputStream fis = getAssets().open("phonetest.html" ) ) {
    String text = "", line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    if (fis != null) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            text += line + "\n";
        }
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(text.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        webView.loadData(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        txtView.setText(text);
    }
} catch( IOException e ) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I expected to see the same webpage.
What can cause this behaviour?

I am using:
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708, built on November 9, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.4.0-169-generic

Comment: not sure if you've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata) perhaps you can find an answer to this from there ?

Comment: It works with ```.loadDataWithBaseURL```, thanks @a_local_nobody

Answer (score -1):

Use this code below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

    txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));

   } else {

    txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

          }
```

Comment: OP is asking about loading a webview, why would this make any difference ?

Comment: If you want to view  HTML text, with out using WebView.